When using turtle-graphics in Java on Mac,the background color of the JButtons is not changing as expected
I want to create a program that randomly creates the number of horizontal and vertical grid layouts and fills them with the numbers that come out by rolling a dice. The screen size is 500×500, the number of horizontal and vertical rows is set to 1~10, and the dice button is expressed in six colors.
However, the background color is not applied.It just has a white(clear) background applied.
this is the code
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class javaCode {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("주사위 채우기");

        int rowNum = (int)((Math.random()*10+1));
        int colNum = (int)((Math.random()*10+1));
        int btnCount = rowNum*colNum;

        Color[] colorAry = {null, Color.lightGray, Color.BLUE, Color.CYAN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.PINK, Color.RED };

        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(rowNum, colNum, 5,5));
        JButton[] btn = new JButton[btnCount];

        for (int i=0; i<btnCount; i++) {
            int diceNum = (int)((Math.random()*6+1));
            btn[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(diceNum));
            btn[i].setOpaque(true);
            btn[i].setBackground(colorAry[diceNum]);
            frame.add(btn[i]);
        }

        frame.setSize(500,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

}


I tried adding this but Nothing has changed
btn[i].repaint();
